# DNN 7 (Latest) Search results have empty hrefs

Tags: search, dotnetnuke

I have some really strange problem here:
The DNN's built in search returning results (this is working as it should), but some of the items have empty hrefs (no link). At this moment i have figured out next things:
1) SearchItem have correct link if i'm searching for page title, for example "Home"
2) SearchItem is missing its href value if i'm trying to search modules content, for example "good" word.
3) The SearchResult.ascx is ok, because "/desktopmodules/internalservices/API/searchService/search?search=home&pageIndex=1&pageSize=15&sortOption=0&culture=en-US" this ajax page, which is called by dnn.SearchResult.js, is missing URLs also.

If my explanation was a bit tricky you can try the search on your own:
1) The first and second links are OK, but the rest are missing hrefs, [The Link 1](http://www.demibit.com/Search?Search=Home)
2) All the links are missing hrefs, [The Link 2](http://www.demibit.com/Search?Search=Chrome)

I'm trying to find the solution for about 3 days, help is really needed.

P.S.
I have EasyDnnNews, EasyDnnGallery and Ozone skin installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of this the content that is related to your third-party modules is the content that isn't working as you would desire.  That is most likely due to the fac that the details from these modules are not properly injecting the content into the ISearchable interface.

Also, if you made changes to any of these modules, be sure to do a reindex of the whole site.